# How to transfer testdata in testlink from one server to another?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, test

Last month we installed testlink and bugzilla on our server and we started writing testcases in testlink for our project.

Unfortunately we've never been able to access testlink on that server.  We always get "500 - Internal Server error".  So we installed testlink on another server and we have a backup of all the installed files on the old server.

How can we transfer our testdata from the other server to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to backup the database from the first server and restore it on the second server. All the test data is stored in the database.

The process for doing this depends on what type of database you are using.